# Python Update an Object from Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have an object `User`, and I have a dictionary of attributes that needs to be updated like `data={'name':"Tom",'age':26}`
I want to iterate over the dictionary and update it
Something like this:

```py
for key,val in data.items():
    user.key=val
```

The problem is it is saying user have no attribute as key. I want to replace user.key as user.name="Tom"

Any solution to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `setattr` function:

```
class User:
    pass


data = {"name": "Tom", "age": 26}

user = User()

for key, value in data.items():
    setattr(user, key, value)

print(f"Name: {user.name}, Age: {user.age}")
```